# Convert multidimensional dictionary to url post string

Tags: c#, http, url, post

I have a dictionary where one of the values is another dictionary. I have been using `NameValueCollection` and `WebClient` to convert the dictionary to a URL for posting.

Where I'm stuck now is how to convert this dictionary so that the url is created properly.

To be clear here's a json version of the dictionary:

```
{
    "One" : "Hello",
    "Two" : "World",
    "Three" : {"Sub-One" : "This is an embedded dictionary"}
}
```

And this is the url string I'm trying to get:

`myUrl.com?One=Hello&Two=World&Three[Sub-One]=This%20is%20an%20embedded%20dictionary`

Is there a library or utility out there for this?

Answer (score 1):

You could look at ServiceStack's JSV format: https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/mythz_blog/blob/master/pages/176.md available in the [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) nuget package as this should accomplish what you need.

The only difference is that it'll use JSON style ":" rather than "=" between keys and values, e.g.

`{One:Hello,Two:World:Three:[{Sub-One:This is....}]}`

but it is safe to use as query string.

Comment: FYI, here's link to docs on using [JSV for complex querystring](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization#passing-complex-objects-in-the-query-string).